# Laravel - Paginate function doesn't working on query building using IF

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using paginate() on my Controller to pass data to the View. This is my index function using the paginate()

```
$userData = User::with('jobUnit')
                        ->select('nip','name','address','phone','email','unit_id')
                        ->paginate(10);

        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => $userData
        ]);
```

This is the result:

[image: enter image descriptionasdsadsada here]

In the other function, I needed to add some IF conditions on the queries that is look like this:

```
$keyword = $request->keyword;
        
$searchedData = User::with('jobUnit')->select('nip','name','address','phone','email','unit_id');

if ($request->searchFilter == 'nip') {
   $searchedData->where('nip','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
}

$searchedData->paginate(10);
```

The results is different, which is a problem for me because I am using the pagination links in the View. Here is the results:
[image]

Does the pagination() not working? Because I tried using the get() as well which should returns "Collection", but it was still returning the "Builder" results.

Comment: if that second picture is the dump of `$searchData` that would make sense since that is the Builder object, the returned result from `paginate` would be the Paginator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need another variable to store the return data

`$searchDataPaginated = $searchedData->paginate(10);`

or using the current one if you want

`$searchedData = $searchedData->paginate(10);`

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it was enough by just using the paginate(). It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit the App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class, you need to add the code below inside the boot() function to support the bootstrap paginator.

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

add that functionality to the boot class to look line:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
```

then in your view page use

```
{{$searchedData->links()}}
```